# TeamViewer display ip address instead of generated Your ID

Tags: virtualbox, teamviewer

I have following problem.
My operating system is Windows 8.1.

I have installed VirtualBox which registered new network adapter during installation.

After that TeamViewer works incorrectly. In the "Your ID" field I see two IP addresses of network adapters instead of generated id by TeamViewer.

Question: What should I change to make TeamViewer display again valid "Your ID" ?

Answer (score 14):

I resolved the issue!

Something happened with TeamViewer settings, that is why "your id" field was displaying ip address. This happens when TeamViewer configured for LAN connections.

(Why TeamViewer settings were lost is still question for me :) )

To fix the issue, it is necessary to change network settings:
In TeamViewer open Extras -> Options, and in General category find Network settings and under
Incoming LAN connections, select the accept option.

Answer (score 2):

TeamViewer shows the local IP address if it doesn't have a working internet connection. You can still connect to it over LAN per IP (must be activated in the options).

Answer (score 0):

Click Settings button and deactivate incoming LAN Connection that worked for me